# Efficient use of Map, Reduce, or filter to find information from given array of objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, list-comprehension

```js
ordersList = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "chicken Burger",
      sellPrice: 20,
      buyPrice: 15,
      qty: 5
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Beef Burger",
      sellPrice: 22,
      buyPrice: 16,
      qty: 3
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "Chicken Sandwich",
      sellPrice: 15,
      buyPrice: 13,
      qty: 2
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Beef Burger",
      sellPrice: 22,
      buyPrice: 16,
      qty: 2
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Chicken Sandwich",
      sellPrice: 15,
      buyPrice: 13,
      qty: 2
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Chicken Sandwich",
      sellPrice: 15,
      buyPrice: 13,
      qty: 20
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "Beef Burger",
      sellPrice: 15,
      buyPrice: 13,
      qty: 10
    }
  ]
]
```

**A new Objects should be created with item-title(key), (Total Quantity,
Total BuyPrice, and Total SellPrice)(value) from the given JSON DATA.The purpose of this question is to find how list comprehension, immutable state,functional style can be used to find the data given below.**

example-`{ 'chicken Burger': { totalQty: 5, buySumPrice: 75, sellSumPrice: 100 },
  'Beef Burger': { totalQty: 15, buySumPrice: 210, sellSumPrice: 260 },
  'Chicken Sandwich': { totalQty: 24, buySumPrice: 312, sellSumPrice: 360 } }`

```js
function getAll() {
  var total = {};
  ordersList.map(function(orders) {
    orders.map(function(order) {
      total[order.name] = total[order.name] ? ({
        qty: (total[order.name]).qty + order.qty,
        buySumPrice:(total[order.name]).buySumPrice + order.buyPrice*order.qty ,
        sellSumPrice: (total[order.name]).sellSumPrice + order.sellPrice*order.qty
      }) : ({
        qty: order.qty,
        buySumPrice: order.buyPrice*order.qty,
        sellSumPrice: order.sellPrice*order.qty
      });
    });
  });
  return total;
}
```

Is it possible to removing the outer total {} by returning the  constructed array from the maps. Also using reduce to do the calculation for summation.

Comment: What did you try? Add some code.

Comment: That isn't JSON, it's an array. JSON is a string format.

Comment: This question reads like it has been copied directly from a school assignment.  Please show what you have tried to solved the problem.

Comment: Why should we bother to help you if you can't be bothered to do the minimum yourself? The other purpose of the question is to see if you've been paying attention in class.

Comment: The question was edited with a possible solution. I was wondering if it was possible to find a neater solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a real bear of a problem here. I'm going to solve it using ES6 because it has a couple of tools that makes this kind of thing much easier. If you need the ES5, copy/paste this into [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl) or add a build step to your application.

```
const getData = ordersList => {
  let merge = ({totalQty=0, buySumPrice=0, sellSumPrice=0}={}, {qty, buyPrice, sellPrice}) => ({
    totalQty: totalQty + qty,
    buySumPrice: buySumPrice + (qty * buyPrice),
    sellSumPrice: sellSumPrice + (qty * sellPrice)
  });
  return ordersList.reduce((ys, xs) => {
    xs.forEach(x => Object.assign(ys, {[x.name]: merge(ys[x.name], x)}));
    return ys;
  }, {});
};

let answer = getData(ordersList);

console.log(JSON.stringify(answer, null, "\t"));
```

Output

```
{
    "chicken Burger": {
        "totalQty": 5,
        "buySumPrice": 75,
        "sellSumPrice": 100
    },
    "Beef Burger": {
        "totalQty": 15,
        "buySumPrice": 210,
        "sellSumPrice": 260
    },
    "Chicken Sandwich": {
        "totalQty": 24,
        "buySumPrice": 312,
        "sellSumPrice": 360
    }
}
```

---

**Remarks:**

The ugliest part of this problem is that the Arrays are nested. If you could afford to `flatten` the `Array(Array(Object{}))` structure to `Array(Object{})`, it would be a much nicer problem. However, that would require iterating through your list twice. For reasonably large inputs, that computational overhead could be a deal breaker.